# understanding the convolution of random variable formula

Tags: probability, random-variables, convolution, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

Consider summing two iid exponential r.v. We know for a fact that this is Gamma distribution with $\alpha = 2, \beta = \theta$. However, when using the convolution formula $Z=X+Y$, we have
$$
f(z)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)f(z-x)dx = \int_{0}^\infty f(x)f(z-x)dx
$$
because $x\in(0,\infty)$ not $x \in (0,z)$, It leads to divergence and sums to infinity, what is the intuition behind integrating to $z$ and not infinity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)$ has support on $x > 0$ as you correctly note.

Therefore $f(z-x) = 0$ whenever $z - x < 0 \iff z < x$

---

**UPDATE**

From the definition of the exponential random variable, $f(y) = 0$ if $y<0$. Thus,
letting $y = z-x$, we have $f(z-x) = 0$ if $z-x<0 \iff z < x \iff x > z$. Thus, the product $f(x)f(z-x)$ is nonzero only when $x > 0$ and $x < z$, which means we should only be integrating over $x \in (0,z)$, since the product vanishes elsewhere.

Comment: please elaborate on where $z-x<0$ comes from

Comment: @smaillis please see the ujpdate